# How to make Hadoop/EMR use more containers per node

Tags: hadoop, hadoop2, emr

I'm in the process of moving our application from Hadoop 1.0.3 to 2.7, on EMR v5.1.0. I got it running, but I'm still having problems getting my head around the resource-allocation system in Yarn. With the default settings provided by EMR, Hadoop only allocates one container per node, even if I select a larger instance type for the nodes. This is a problem, since we'll now be using twice as many nodes to do the same amount of work.

I want to squeeze more containers into one node, *and* ensure that we're using all the available resources. I assume that I shouldn't touch `yarn.nodemanager.resource.memory-mb` or  `yarn.nodemanager.resource.cpu-vcores`, since those are set by EMR to reflect the actual available resources. Which settings do I have to change?

Comment: What is the value set for `yarn.nodemanager.resource.memory-mb` by default and how much memory do you have on each node?

Answer (score 1):

Your container sizes are defined by setting the memory (default criteria for a container) and vcores. The following can be configured:

1. yarn-scheduler.minimum-allocation-mb
2. yarn-scheduler.maximum-allocation-mb
3. yarn-scheduler.increment-allocation-mb
4. yarn-scheduler.minimum-allocation-vcores
5. yarn-scheduler.maximum-allocation-vcores
6. yarn-scheduler.increment-allocation-vcores

All the following criteria must be satified (they are per container, except for yarn.nodemanager.resource.cpu-vcores and yarn.nodemanager.resource.memory-mb which are per NodeManager hence per DataNode):

1 <= yarn-scheduler.minimum-allocation-vcores <= yarn-scheduler.maximum-allocation-vcores

yarn-scheduler.maximum-allocation-vcores <= yarn.nodemanager.resource.cpu-vcores

yarn-scheduler.increment-allocation-vcores = 1

1024 <= yarn-scheduler.minimum-allocation-mb <= yarn-scheduler.maximum-allocation-mb

yarn-scheduler.maximum-allocation-mb <= yarn.nodemanager.resource.memory-mb

yarn-scheduler.increment-allocation-mb = 512

You can also see this helpful link https://www.cloudera.com/documentation/enterprise/5-4-x/topics/cdh_ig_yarn_tuning.html